# Estimating acoustic sound signal energy radiated

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, frequency-domain, signal-energy, noise-cancellation

Im recording sound generated by a drilling machine against an object. I have the recording of following :

1. Ambient noise with drilling machine switched off.
2. Drilling machine on+ambient noise
3. Drilling machine on and drilling against a surface+ambient noise.

Recordings are done in terms of dB vs time.

With that I have following queries:

1. Can i use this data to find Pressure vs time domain ?
2. How do i then isolate Pressure vs time domain data by subtracting ambient noise & drilling machine idle noise (Not used against a surface) ?
3. How do i use data in 2. to find acoustic sound signal energy radiated ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use this data to find Pressure vs time domain ?

unless your "dB vs time" is already coming from a calibrated system, and dB refers to some specific physical sound pressure: no.

In general, microphones, amplifiers, audio converters are *not* calibrated. So, your decibels are relative to some arbitrary unknown maximum signal amplitude.

What you can do is *calibrate* your system with a source of known acoustic power – but that's going to be very hard. You'd want to take your measurement setup to someone who otherwise calibrates microphones.

So, 2. and 3. fall flat because 1. isn't possible. Generally, you could really just subtract the averages, but assuming your "dB" are in terms of power, things already get a bit hairy when you calculate a PSD from that – it would be a power-power spectrum density estimate, and you need to be careful not to fall prey to assumptions on the actual acoustic spectra based on that (for that, it would be necessary to work based on the amplitudes, not powers).

Comment: Yes i am recording the sound using factory calibrated larson davis spark 705+ dosimeter as well as B&K TYPE 2270 sound level meter.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use this data to find Pressure vs time domain ?

If the data is in dBSPL and properly calibrated, then yes. Otherwise no.

> How do i then isolate Pressure vs time domain data by subtracting ambient noise & drilling machine idle noise (Not used against a surface) ?

Depends on the details of your data. I would imagine that the drilling machine is considerably louder than the ambient noise in which case you can simply ignore the ambient noise. If it's close in level, you may have to do spectral subtraction.

> How do i use data in 2. to find acoustic sound signal energy radiated ?

You can't. Even if it's calibrated, the measurement is only a single point in space. The pressure at one location doesn't tell you a whole lot about the total radiated energy of the source. To do this you would need lots of measurements from a "dense enough" spatial grid around the source or characterize the sound source in a specific well known acoustic environment: typically that's "reverb chamber" or "diffuse field chamber"

Comment: Yes i am recording the sound using factory calibrated larson davis spark 705+ dosimeter as well as B&K TYPE 2270 sound level meter.

Comment: Yes my drilling machine noise is substantially higher than ambient noise of my laboratory. Im trying to find pressure domain data generated during drilling which means i want to exclude pressure data generated from machine when drill unit is just rotating (i.e not used against a surface).